# Unable to load DLL 'SQLite.Interop.dll'

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, sqlite

Periodically I am getting the following exception:

`Unable to load DLL 'SQLite.Interop.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)`

I am using 1.0.82.0. version, installing it with nuget in VS2010, OS Win7 64.

Once exception starts to appear, it appears constantly - in debug and release and running application within or outside VS.

The only way to stop it is logoff and logon. The exception is not thrown and dll is loaded.
It can work for days, but then it can break again.

Has anyone seen something like this and is there a solution for it?

Comment: Yes, it's set to copy always. I have x64 and x86 folders in bin/debug. And it works mostly, but sometimes just stops to work. Probably something is blocking the access to the dll, I will try to find it out next time it stops to work. As I said it may work days without any problems.

Comment: I got this error right out of the box after adding the SQLite nuget package to a new console project. Manually copying SQLite.Interop.dll from the x86 folder up one level allows the app to run. Seems strange to me that this would be so broken.

Comment: @Wayne Yes, this definitely helps. But in my case, we are working together on the project, and my friend is using x86, while me x64 OS. And as I noticed, it just stops to work sometimes. Though it didnt happen to me last month.

Comment: If you download correct binary for SQLite then copy SQLite.Interop.dll into your Release or Debug folder according to your project build option.

Comment: This is such a random bug... sometimes it occurs and sometimes it doesn't for my project.  Tried everything.

Comment: I ran into several problems like this. The solution that worked for me was to use the statically linked version of the library.

Comment: For me it works on run and on debug, but not on d:DesignInstance (wpf). I fixed it by copying the dll up into the project directory, but after rebooting, that's not working anymore. I don't get it.

Comment: OK... I changed it to x86 only - still not working. Reverted the change... f'ing WORKS!

Answer (score 94, accepted):

So, after adding the NuGet the deployment doesn't copy down the Interops.  You can add this to your csproj file and it should fix that behavior:

```
 <PropertyGroup> 
    <ContentSQLiteInteropFiles>true</ContentSQLiteInteropFiles>
    <CopySQLiteInteropFiles>false</CopySQLiteInteropFiles>
    <CleanSQLiteInteropFiles>false</CleanSQLiteInteropFiles>
    <CollectSQLiteInteropFiles>false</CollectSQLiteInteropFiles>
 </PropertyGroup>
```

If you look in the source for NuGet for SQLite you can see what these are doing specifically.  This allowed me to get a deploy working with ASP.Net Core.

Comment: ContentSQLiteInteropFiles is the answer.  Most of the top answers are guesswork.

Comment: Yes, ContentSQLiteInteropFiles is the answer.
1. This should be the accepted answer
2. On the other hand, it should be investigated, that as a nuget package how to make this work automatically, or at least document the need for this configuration.

Comment: Should be the accepted answer. Super simple. 1. unload project 2. add the above to csproj 3. reload project. it's that easy...

Comment: Note that this solution is for "old" style projects only.  For an answer that works for "new" style projects too, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/60176344/448129

Comment: How does one arrive at such a solution? Is there some documentation as to what exactly adding this code does? Would very much appreciate more info.

Comment: It does seem to work, and yet I still get a failure at runtime. Manually copying SQLite.Interop.dll to the Debug/Release dir is the only thing that works for me.

Comment: This happens to me when I converted the old project to .NET 4.8. Before it was no such item as `ContentSQLiteInteropFiles` in the Project file (I checked in version control) yet it worked well. After I upgraded to .NET 4.8 and updated all NuGets to the latest version, this problem appears. `ContentSQLiteInteropFiles` fixed this for me.

Answer (score 161):

I know I'm late to the party but I had this issue right after I pulled down latest x86/x64 today (version 1.0.88.0). My local IIS in VS2012 runs 32bit by default and there's no easy way to switch to x64. My production server runs 64bit.

Anyway I installed the NuGet package to a DLL project and I got this error. What I had to do to get it working I had to **install it to the main site** project, too. Even if it doesn't touch SQLite classes at all.

My guess is that SQLite uses the entry assembly to detect which version of Interop to load.

Comment: It worked for me after I added the reference to SQLite Core with NuGet to the main project.

Comment: Adding sqllite.core to main project worked for me on my WPF solution

Comment: I had to do both install-package Sqlite as well as Install-Package System.Data.SQLite.Core into my website even though the db calls are in a library...

Comment: This should be the answer.

Comment: This worked for me using VS 2017. I installed System.Data.SQLite into one project and only needed System.Data.SQLite.Core referenced in my startup project.

Comment: What do you mean by "main site" project? In my case I am doing desktop work. Do you mean the "startup" project?

Comment: Well you're right and it is not ideal. I tried to copy the interop dll from the post build event and it doesn't even work. These dll seem to appear in the x86/x64 AFTER the post-build event is called .. somewhat useless.

Comment: @DaveInCaz - That worked for me. I have a command line app that calls a dll that uses sqlite. Including sqlite in the command line app solved this issue.

Comment: This worked for me after installing the System.Data.SQLite.Core nuget package to my Startup project (VS 2019)

Comment: It worked for me too. But why? If I have added Nuget to by BL library and referenced that BL in Web/Desktop project, it should bring that files/DLLs

Comment: @LucaCremonesi - Thank you, that was exactly the cause of this error in my own project.  For everyone's reference, System.Data.SQLite is referenced and used only in a DLL that is part of the Solution, but I did have to add System.Data.SQLite.Core to the MAIN Project (in this case, a Forms Project) in order to fix this Interop DLL Exception.

Answer (score 91):

I had this problem because a dll I was using had Sqlite as a dependency (configured in NuGet with only the Sqlite core package.). The project compiles and copies all the Sqlite dll-s except the 'SQLite.Interop.dll' (both x86 and x64 folder).

The solution was very simple: just add the System.Data.SQLite.Core package as a dependency (with NuGet) to the project you are building/running and the dll-s will be copied.

Comment: Agreed. I'm using the 'Sqlite.Net PCL' package but found I also needed 'System.Data.SQLite Core (x86/x64)'. I also had to change the project(s) referencing it to use a Platform target of 'x86' or 'x64', rather than 'Any CPU'.

Comment: Tried quite a few solutions posted here, this one actually worked out best.

Comment: How can you add a dependency like that? never done it (VS2013)

Comment: Go to Tools -> NuGet Package Manager -> Manage NuGet Packages for Solution... -> Online -> All. Then Search for sqlite and add System.Data.SQLite Core (x86/x64).

Comment: Did you mean"System.Data.SQLite.Core" ? I don't see any package called "Sqlite.Core". Thanks

Comment: @Marin Online? I don't see that in Manage Nuget Packages for Solution

Comment: Also, I think SQLite Core is installed. and yet fails :(

Comment: It has probably changed a bit since 2015 (as I was using VS2012). Unfortunately, I don't have VS installed any more so I can't check how it is done now.

Comment: Yes for example in my case I have  DLL which uses SQLite -- whose build correctly copies the interop DLL to its bin/release/x64 and bin/release/x32 directories. But then I also have a separate test DLL, which contains the unit tests -- the unit test's build copies the system under test but not the interop DLLs, to the release directory of the test DLL.

Comment: Excellent Marin, your comment helped me greatly!

Answer (score 51):

I had this same problem when using SQLite in a WPF project whose platform target was `Any CPU`. I fixed it by following the following steps:

1. Open the project designer in Visual Studio. Details on how to do it can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z15yzzew.aspx).
2. Click on the Build tab.
3. Disable the `prefer 32-bit` option.

Alternatively, you could just set the platform target to `x86` or `x64`. I think this problem is caused by the `System.Data.SQLite` library using the platform target to get the location of the 'SQLite.Interop.dll' file.

UPDATE:

In case the project designer cannot be reached, just open the project (`*.csproj`) file from a text editor and add the value `<Prefer32Bit>false</Prefer32Bit>` into the `<PropertyGroup>...</PropertyGroup>` tag.

Example code

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProjectGuid>[Set by Visual Studio]</ProjectGuid>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <AppDesignerFolder>Properties</AppDesignerFolder>
    <RootNamespace>[Set by Visual Studio]</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>[Set by Visual Studio]</AssemblyName>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.5</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <FileAlignment>[Set by Visual Studio]</FileAlignment>
    <!--Add the line below to your project file. Leave everything else untouched-->
    <Prefer32Bit>false</Prefer32Bit>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: I am using VS 2010, there is no such option.

Comment: @xll, I edited the answer for clarification. Check if the edit clears things up.

Comment: I had this problem when I tried to start application in VS 2012 debug mode with target platform AnyCPU, and disabling the `Prefer 32-bit` option worked for me.

Comment: The option was not checked by default, but checking it then unchecking it worked!

Comment: In VS2012 this option is grayed out for me.

Comment: The option is only enabled on EXE projects, but I think most of us have this issue with unit test projects.

Comment: Was greyed out for me in a WPF project in VS Pro 2015.  `.csproj` file had it set to `false` already, but still had the error.

Answer (score 35):

This is how I fixed it in my project.

It was working, and when a colleague submitted his changes, I received the "Unable to load DLL 'SQLite.Interop.dll'" exception.

Diffing the project's .csproj file, this was in the NON-WORKING version:

```
<ItemGroup>
     <Content Include="x64\SQLite.Interop.dll" />
     <Content Include="x86\SQLite.Interop.dll" />
</ItemGroup>
```

And this is what the WORKING version had:

```
<ItemGroup>
     <Content Include="x64\SQLite.Interop.dll">
          <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      </Content>
      <Content Include="x86\SQLite.Interop.dll">
          <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      </Content>
</ItemGroup>
```

After reverting back, I didn't receive the exception.  The DLL files were dumped in the appropriate Debug\x64 (etc) folders.

Comment: <itemgroup> for "SQLite.Interop.dll" is not there in project's .csproj file. still i tried to add your solution but didn't work :(

Comment: This will not work in VS2012, the elements do not exist.

Comment: Thank  you very much. Works  in 2015 vs.

Comment: I tried using a <copy> based on the build type but it was not working for unit tests.  The OutDir was not correct.  By copying the "x86" and "x64" folders I guess sqlite (or maybe .net) found what it needed.  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 27):

When you get in this state, try performing a Rebuild-All. If this fixes the problem, you may have the same issue I had.

**Some background (my understanding)**:

- SQLite has 1 managed assembly (System.Data.SQLite.dll) and several
  platform specific assemblies (SQLite.Interop.dll). When installing
  SQLite with Nuget, Nuget will add the platform specific assemblies to your project
  (within several folders: \x86, \x64), and configures these
  dlls to "Copy Always".
- Upon load, the managed assembly will search for platform
  specific assemblies inside the \x86 and \x64 folders. You can see
  more on that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3787428/loading-x86-or-x64-assembly/6060754#6060754). The exception is this managed
  assembly attempting to find the relevant (SQLite.Interop.dll) inside
  these folders (and failing).

**My Scenario**:

I have 2 projects in my solution; a WPF app, and a class library. The WPF app references the class library, and the class library references SQLite (installed via Nuget).

The issue for me was when I modify only the WPF app, VS attempts to do a partial rebuild (realizing that the dependent dll hasn't changed). Somewhere in this process, VS cleans the content of the \x86 and \x64 folders (blowing away SQLite.Interop.dll). When I do a full Rebuild-All, VS copies the folders and their contents correctly.

**My Solution**:

To fix this, I ended up adding a Post-Build process using xcopy to force copying the \x86 and \x64 folders from the class library to my WPF project \bin directory.

Alternatively, you could do fancier things with the build configuration / output directories.

Comment: The message I got was telling me that those files were missing but I thought it was a permission issue.  Once I saw your message i realized they never actually made it to the server when I deployed.

Comment: My near identical solution was to add x86 and x64 folders to my startup project, then add the x86 interop and x64 interop files within their respective folders. I set the files' option to "content" and "build always." This is the only way I could get my Windows Forms app to connect to an embedded s3db database file when I deployed the app with ClickOnce to other PC's. Frustratingly, I didn't have an SQLite error when I developed and tested the app on my PC.

Comment: Still happening with VS 2017 :'(

Comment: This is the answer that helps me understand my problem, although my fix is a bit different. My problem is that I added the system.data.Sqlite.dll manually. In this way the Sqlite.Interop.dll is not automatically copied to \x86 and x64. The fix is to delete the reference and add it by Nuget.

Answer (score 19):

I had the same issue running Visual Studio Express 2013. I tried several solutions mentioned here and elsewhere to no avail. I hope this fix helps others.

I fixed it by using the [`DeploymentItem` attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.deploymentitemattribute.aspx) on my test class that tests the SQLite-based service.

Example:

```
[TestClass]
[DeploymentItem(@"x86\SQLite.Interop.dll", "x86")] // this is the key
public class LocalStoreServiceTests
{

    [TestMethod]
    public void SomeTestThatWasFailing_DueToThisVeryIssue()
    {
         // ... test code here
    }
}
```

This causes the needed `SQLite.Interop.dll` to get copied to the `x86` directory within the appropriate "TestResults" folder.

All is green. All is good.

Comment: This solution works only if you are using the Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting namespace

Comment: This is a correct solution if you're using MSTest. SQLite worked fine, finding the SQLite.Interop.dll with no issue, until I used DeploymentItem("some.csv") for a test. Including the .csv file in that way triggered MSTest to copy all referenced dlls over to the TestResults directory. Since SQLite.Interop.dll is not referenced in the project (and cannot be since it's unmanaged code), it never got copied over.

Comment: Your best bet is to add two lines, one for each architecture.  That protects you in the event the test runner happens to be running 64-bit.

Answer (score 19):

## old project file format

*i.e. projects beginning with `<Project ToolsVersion="3.5" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">`*

Add the following to your csproj on your "main"/root project

```
<PropertyGroup> 
    <ContentSQLiteInteropFiles>true</ContentSQLiteInteropFiles>
    <CopySQLiteInteropFiles>false</CopySQLiteInteropFiles>
    <CleanSQLiteInteropFiles>false</CleanSQLiteInteropFiles>
    <CollectSQLiteInteropFiles>false</CollectSQLiteInteropFiles>
</PropertyGroup>
```

## new SDK project file format

*i.e. projects beginning with `<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.*">`*

Add `PrivateAssets="none"` to each ProjectReference/PackageImport in the dependency chain down to the System.Data.Sqlite PackageImport

ex:

```
<PackageReference Include="System.Data.SQLite.Core" Version="1.0.110" PrivateAssets="none"/>
```

Comment: ouput successfully show:
Copying file from "..\packages\System.Data.SQLite.Core.1.0.105.2\build\net451\x64\SQLite.Interop.dll" to "XXProject\release\x64\SQLite.Interop.dll".
Copying file from "..\packages\System.Data.SQLite.Core.1.0.105.2\build\net451\x86\SQLite.Interop.dll" to "XXProject\release\x86\SQLite.Interop.dll".

Comment: Please EVBD use this solution, and never just copying the dll manually!!

Answer (score 18):

Updating NuGet from `Tools -> Extension and updates` and reinstalling SQLite.Core with the command `PM> Update-Package -reinstall System.Data.SQLite.Core` fixed it for me.

Comment: If you get an error when doing this, removing my SQLite DLLs/references and completely reinstalling them from nuget did the trick for me

Comment: reinstall sqllite core help to me too. Occured at VS2012. VS didn't include x62 version to web deploy package

Comment: Fixed for me too in VS2015 Professional.

Answer (score 10):

I had a similar issue in a multiple projects solution. The SQLite.Interop.dll was necessary for one of the plugins distributed with the software using ClickOnce.

As far as debugging in visual studio everything worked fine, but the deployed version was missing the folders x86/ and x64/ containing that DLL.

The solution to have it work after deployment using ClickOnce was to create in the startup project of the solution (also the one being published) these two subfolder, copy into them the DLLs and set them as Content Copy Always.

This way the ClickOnce publishing tool automatically includes these files and folders in the manifest and deploys the software with them

Comment: this was the only solution that worked for me... and boy.. was it a pain to debug when your app just closes on a user's pc.

Answer (score 9):

There are really a lot of answers here, but mine is simple and clear with *no-GAC-playing-around*.

The problem was, the executable File needs a copy of the right `SQLite.Interop.dll` (x86 or x64) to access our Database.

Mostly architectures have layers and in my case the *Data Layer* has the required DLL for SQLite Connection.

So i simple put a post build script into my *Data Layer* Solution and everything worked fine.

---

## TL;DR;

1. Set all Projects of your solution to `x86` or `x64` in the build options.
2. Add following `Post-Build-Script` to the Project with the `SQLite nuget Package`:

   `xcopy  "$(TargetDir)x64" "$(SolutionDir)bin\Debug\" /y`

Of course you have to change the script for `Release Build` and `x86` builds.

---

## STL;DR;

Put your `SQLite.Interop.dll` next to the `*.exe` File.

Answer (score 7):

The default installation of the multi-architecture (x86, x64) version of SQLite from NuGet exhibits the behavior that you described.  If you would like to load the correct version for actual architecture that the .NET runtime chose to run your application on your machine, then you can give the DLL loader a hint about where to locate the correct library as follows:

Add a declaration for the kernel32.dll function call to SetDLLDirectory() before your Program.Main():

```
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = System.Runtime.InteropServices.CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
    [return: System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAs(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    static extern bool SetDllDirectory(string lpPathName);
```

Then use your own method for determining the correct subdirectory to find the architecture specific version of 'SQLite.Interop.dll'.  I use the following code:

```
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        int wsize = IntPtr.Size;
        string libdir = (wsize == 4)?"x86":"x64";
        string appPath = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath);
        SetDllDirectory(System.IO.Path.Combine(appPath, libdir));
```

Answer (score 5):

even if it is an old post, I'd like to share the solution that I found here:
http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/info/54e52d4c6f

If you don't want to read all the issue, the solution is to copy the file "msvcr100.dll" (that can be found in Windows\System32 directory) in the same path as SQLite.Interop.dll.

I would advice to read the issue to understand why, and to include the file in your setup but to install it only if the error occurs, I made it an optional component selectable in the setup options.

HTH,
Formentz

Comment: Thanks so much for this, I tried everything else and this was the solution

Comment: Thankyou. This solution fix my problem.

Answer (score 5):

I don't know why this has not been included yet, but I had to do the research and find this out for myself, so hopefully someone will find this answer and be saved the trouble.  This was for a WPF app.  It worked fine on my Dev box, but did not work on the computer where I was copying it and got the `Unable to load DLL 'SQLite.Interop.dll'` error.  I ported over all of its associated directories and files, directly from my "Debug" folder to this other computer when I got the same error as the OP when I ran it.  My "bin" folder that contained my DLLs had been copied to "Debug\bin" and all were included, along with my application files when I did my copying to the other computer using this path, so it was not missing any files.

Things I saw said in other answers that did not apply:

- I did not use the NuGet package or need to create x86 or x64 folders that it seems that NuGet package creates.  My DLLs (System.Data.SQLite and SQLite.Interop.dll, along with System.Data.SQLite.config) are in the "bin" folder in my project and were copied in manually (create "bin" folder in Solution Explorer in VS, paste DLLs into this folder in Windows Explorer, use Add > Existing Item to bring files into VS folder/project).  Then I reference them as Referenced Assemblies in my project using that location ("References" > "Add Reference", and browse to one, [rinse, repeat](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=rinse%2C%20repeat) for the rest).  This ensures my project knows exactly where they are.
- I did not need to reference any SQLite DLL file in my app.config or even touch my  MyProject.csproj file.
- I did not even need to specify a particular processor!  My project's build is for "Any CPU", even though I have only mixed or 64-bit DLLs and will only be running on Windows 7+, which are 64-bit OSes. (no x86-only/32-bit solely DLLs)
- I was already specifying them as "Content" and "copy if newer" for these DLLs when I experienced the OP's error.

What I found was this, from https://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/faq.wiki#q20 :

> **(11) Why do I get a DllNotFoundException (for "sqlite3.dll" or "SQLite.Interop.dll") when trying to run my application?**
>
> Either the named dynamic link library (DLL) cannot be located or it cannot be loaded due to missing dependencies. Make sure the named dynamic link library is located in the application directory or a directory along the system PATH and try again. **Also, be sure the necessary Visual C++ runtime redistributable has been installed** unless you are using a dynamic link library that was built statically linked to it.

Emphasis mine on that bolded part inside the paragraph.  The target computer was fresh and had no programs loaded except .NET 4.0.  Once I installed C++, it was able to complete the commands to SQLite.  This should have been one of the first FAQs and part of the pre-requisities, but it was buried at #11.  My development computer already had it loaded because it came with Visual Studio, so that's why it worked, there.

**Download:**
Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48145

Update 3 (cumulative update): 
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53587

Answer (score 5):

As the [SQLite wiki](https://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki) says, your application deployment must be:

[image: Application deployment]

So you need to follow the rules. Find dll that matches your target platform and put it in location, describes in the picture. Dlls can be found in YourSolution/packages/System.Data.SQLite.Core.%version%/.

I had problems with application deployment, so I just added right SQLite.Interop.dll into my project, the added x86 folder to AppplicationFolder in setup project and added file references to dll.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue. Please follow these steps:

1. Make sure you have installed `System.Data.SQLite.Core` package by
   `SQLite Development Team` from `NuGet`.
2. Go to project solution and try to locate `build` folder inside `packages` folder
3. Check your project framework and pick the desired SQLite.Interop.dll and place it in your debug/release folder

[Reference](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CMwfDN_Zg1M)

Comment: Thanks, I was using different version of .net framework. The reference video was helpful.

Answer (score 4):

Copy "SQLite.Interop.dll" files for both x86 and x64 in debug folder. these files should copy into "x86" and "x64 folders in debug folder.

Answer (score 3):

You could also get this error if you are trying to run a 32 bit dll, in a 64 bit project.

I got this when I have placed the same file(SQLite.Interop.dll in 32 bit version) in both the x86 and x64 folder.

Answer (score 3):

If you [download correct binary](http://www.sqlite.org/download.html) for `SQLite` then copy `SQLite.Interop.dll` into your *Release* or *Debug* folder according to your project build option.

Answer (score 3):

I have started using Costura.Fody to package (.net) assemblies and embed and preload native dlls. This also helps later, with distribution as you can send one file.

1. Install Costura Fody from Nuget.
2. In your C# project create a folder called costrua32. In there add any native dlls you which C# to load.
3. Once you have added them to this folder. Click on the properties window and change build action to "Embedded Resource"
4. Finally you need to amend the XML file called FodyWeavers.xml as follows. Here I am specifying load the sql dll first. (note you drop the .dll)

   ```
   Weavers
    Costura
     PreloadOrder
      SQLite.Interop
      tbb_debug
      tbb
     /PreloadOrder>
    /Costura
   /Weavers
   ```

The advantage of this is that you do not have to write any pre or post build events, and the end product is totally encapsulated in to one larger file.

Comment: Folder name should be costura32, documentation https://github.com/Fody/Costura#native-libraries-and-preloadorder

Answer (score 3):

Also added the dll to the test project (through Nuget Manager) and it fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

Could there be contention for the assembly?  Check to see whether there's another application with a file lock on the DLL.

If this is the reason, it should be easy to use a tool like [Sysinternal's Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) to discover the offending program.

HTH,
Clay

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem because Visual C++ 2010 redistributable no installed in my PC.if you have not already installed Visual c++ 2010 redistributable [Download](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5555) and install this(check x86 or 64 dll).

Comment: Yes. This was my case too ... only mine was requireing Visual C++ 2010 redistributable SP1. Best soulution is to read carefully which runtime is required for your version. For example here: http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki

Comment: Latest link: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads

Answer (score 2):

I got the same problem. However, finally, I can fix it.  Currently, I use Visual Studio 2013 Community Edition.  I just use **Add->Existing Item...** and browse to where the SQLite.Data.SQLite files are in (my case is 'C:\Program Files (x86)\System.Data.SQLite\2013\bin').  Please don't forget to change type of what you will include to **Assembly Files (*.dll; *.pdb)**.  Choose '**SQLite.Interop.dll**' in that folder.  From there and then, I can continue without any problems at all.  Good luck to you all. ^_^
P.S. I create web form application.  I haven't tried in window form application or others yet.

Answer (score 2):

Try to set the platform target to x86 or x64 (and not Any CPU) before you build:
Project->Properties->Build->Platform target in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 2):

Copy SQLite.Interop.dll in project directory.

```
src\
  project\
      bin\   <-- Past in bin
         x64\
           SQLite.Interop.dll <-- Copy this if 64
         x86\
           SQLite.Interop.dll <-- Copy this if 32
```

Comment: I had to give IIS_APPPOOL Edit permissions to Bin file to solve the problem. Just copying the ddl was causing an Access Denied to the dll

Comment: Adding these file has solved the issues, but this is a temporary solution.

Answer (score 2):

I've struggled with this for a long time, and, occasionally, I found that the test setting is incorrect. See this image:
[image: Test setting]

I just uncheck the test setting, and the issue disappears. Otherwise, the exception will occurs.
Hopefully, this will help someone.
Not sure it's the root cause.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/14064227)

Comment: In my case, the testsettings file is wrong: <TestSettings ... <Deployment> <DeploymentItem filename="bin\Relase\a.test.dll" . the file location is wrong configured.

Answer (score 2):

My application is a web application (ASP.NET MVC) and I had to change the application pool to run under `LocalSystem` instead of `ApplicationPoolIdentity`. To do this:

1. Open IIS Manager
2. Find the Application Pool your site is running under.
3. Click Advanced Settings from the actions
4. Change Identity to `LocalSystem`

I have no idea why this fixes the issue.

Answer (score 2):

My situation was a little unique. I was running an application inside a docker container and kept getting the following error

> System.DllNotFoundException : Unable to load shared library 'SQLite.Interop.dll' or one of its dependencies. In order to help diagnose loading problems, consider setting the LD_DEBUG environment variable: libSQLite.Interop.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

So I set **LD_DEBUG=libs** to find out what folders **System.Data.SQLite.dll** was looking in to find **SQLite.Interop.dll**.

You can find info on setting **LD_DEBUG** here: http://www.bnikolic.co.uk/blog/linux-ld-debug.html

Once I did that I realized that **SQLite.Interop.dll** was being found just fine. The DLL that wasn't being found was **libSQLite.Interop.dll**. I should have read the entire error message.

Hours of Googling later I found this [guide](http://blog.wezeku.com/2016/10/09/using-system-data-sqlite-under-linux-and-mono/) on how to compile the missing DLL from the SQLite source code.

Note that the file that was actually missing was **libSQLite.Interop.dll.so**

Anyway when you compile the source code you get **libSQLite.Interop.so** which you need to rename to **libSQLite.Interop.dll.so** and put it in the directory that it's looking in which you can find by setting **LD_DEBUG**.

For me the directory that **System.Data.SQLite.dll** was looking in was `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/`

Comment: This worked for me on a Linux machine, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Upgrading to Visual Studio 2019 ver. 16.10 caused the issue for me, where msbuild reported the following for the `System.Data.SQLite.Core`-package:

```
CopySQLiteInteropFiles:
Skipping target "CopySQLiteInteropFiles" because it has no outputs.
```

https://github.com/dotnet/msbuild/issues/6493

Microsoft says the bug has been fixed with ver. 16.10.4. Now just have to wait for AppVeyor to update their Visual Studio Images (Until then one can use `Previous Visual Studio 2019`).

Now AppVeyor is using broken dotnet-build-engine for both current and previous Visual Studio 2019-image. Now one have to explicit install dotnet sdk ver. 5.0.302:

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'https://dot.net/v1/dotnet-install.ps1' -UseBasicParsing -OutFile "$env:temp/dotnet-install.ps1"; & $env:temp\dotnet-install.ps1 -Architecture x64 -Version 5.0.302 -InstallDir "$env:ProgramFiles\dotnet"
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it's a good answer, but I was able to solve this problem by running my application under an AppDomain with an identity of "Local System".

Answer (score 1):

I am working on a simple console application to add some test data to an SQLite database and was getting this error. The configuration for the project is "Any CPU". I fixed it by copying the SQLite.Interop.dll to the bin\debug folder. A better way would be to use the method by @Wil, but how do you specify this for "Any CPU" configuration?

Answer (score 1):

For reference for anyone looking at this question:

If you use the nuget package, it installs a build rule that does the copying for you. (see under System.Data.SQLite.Core.1.0.94.0\build - or whatever version of Core you install).

The nuget installer adds the rule to your project file automatically.

This still doesn't fix the test case problem though. The DeploymentItem (https://stackoverflow.com/a/24411049/89584) approach is the only thing that seems to work there.

Answer (score 1):

I ran across this problem, in a solution with a WebAPI/MVC5 web project and a Feature Test project, that both drew off of the same data access (or, 'Core') project.  I, like so many others here, am using a copy downloaded via NuGet in Visual Studio 2013.

What I did, was in Visual Studio added a x86 and x64 solution folder to the Feature Test and Web Projects.  I then did a `Right Click | Add Existing Item...`, and added the appropriate SQLite.interop.dll library from `..\SolutionFolder\packages\System.Data.SQLite.Core.1.0.94.0\build\net451\[appropriate architecture]` for each of those folders.  I then did a `Right Click | Properties`, and set `Copy to Output Directory` to `Always Copy`.  The next time I needed to run my feature tests, the tests ran successfully.

Answer (score 1):

**In short**

To get this to work also with *NCrunch* I had to add the Interop.dll versions provided with the NuGet package as [additional files in NCrunch configuration](https://www.ncrunch.net/documentation/reference_solution-configuration_additional-files-to-include).

**My case**

I had a C# solution with one project directly depending on SQLite (a helper library) and a unit test project that used this helper library. I had installed System.Data.SQLite.Core version 1.0.97.0 as a NuGet package.

In my case the [workaround provided by Marin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28092497/668194) got it working in Visual Studio and in CI as well. However this would still provide errors in NCrunch.

In NCrunch configuration I added the following path in "Additional files to include" under the unit test projects settings:

```
..\packages\System.Data.SQLite.Core.1.0.97.0\build\net45\**.dll
```

Comment: Stumbled across the same problem and knew it has something to do with ncrunch. Solved my some time.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to posted here because of the complexity of this problem. My solution was to roll back to .Net 4.0. I have been testing for 3 days and have not been able to get System.Data.SQLite.Core.1.0.98.0 to work with .Net 4.5 or .Net 4.5.1.

The testing was exhaustive on 3 computers, 2 servers one dev PC. I have not been able to get to the source of the issue. I have tried editing the .vsproj file. I have added the SQLite.interop.dll to all folders practically. I have applied the package to all GAC folders, and removed and reapplied individually. Eventually removed.

I do have System.Data.SQLite.Core.1.0.98.0 working with .Net 4.0. I intend to continue to attempt the migration, but I think I will start a new project first and see if I can get it to work in that fashion. This was originally a .Net 3.5 web app, and in my travels I found a good amount of information still referencing that framework.

Comment: If you look at the nuget package for 4.5.1, it doesn't have the dll in the build directory. It has it for literally every other version of .net. I "fixed" the problem by going up to 4.7.1.

Comment: FYI 4.7.1 wasn't available back then. No need to post on such an old thread.

Answer (score 1):

Just worked this for me : `Install-Package System.Data.SQLite.Core` on Package Manager Console.

Answer (score 1):

You do need to install System.Data.SQLite.Core via NuGet.
If you use InnoSetup, make sure that you have the following lines in the [Files] section of the .iss file:

```
Source: "C:\YourProjectPath\bin\Release\x64\*"; DestDir: "{app}\x64"; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs
Source: "C:\YourProjectPath\bin\Release\x86\*"; DestDir: "{app}\x86"; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs
```

Change '**YourProjectPath**' for the path to your project.

Comment: The Answer ABOVE is IMHO the only Solution per my Issue which has NOT been able to be resolved by MS Development Team here is a link to my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63679859/file-not-found-error-system-data-sqlite-version-1-0-113-0 and a Strong suggestion is to use Inno Setup back in the dark ages we called this dll HELL when using VB 6 that is when I learned to use Inno Setup Here is good video if your a beginner https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z5g_79_nD-g

Answer (score 1):

This is what worked for me.

1. With Visual Studio open, search and install SQLite.Core via the NUGET Package manager.
2. Go to Solution Explorer in VS, Right click your PROJECT NAME-->ADD-->NEW FOLDER
3. Name the folder x64
4. Repeat the process and add folder and name it x86
5. Right click the x64 folder-->ADD-->EXISTING ITEM Then browse to the DEBUG FOLDER. You will find the x64 folder. Open it and select the "SQLite.Interop.dll" file then hit OK.
6. Repeat step 5 for the x86 folder.
7. Right click the DLL that you just added and select PROPERTIES. In the option Copy to Output Directory, choose Copy always.
8. Repeat step 7 for both DLLs in x64 and x86 folder.

Next time you build the project and take to another computer, it should work fine.

Comment: For me it was enough to install SQLite.Core

Answer (score 1):

I found that when I allowed Nuget to update SQLite to 1.0.115.5 my project no longer needed the 'SQLite.Interop.dll'.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this problem myself, but it turned out to be another cause:

```
System.DllNotFoundException was caught 
Unable to load DLL 'SQLite.Interop.dll': Access is denied.
```

In this case, the code was (indirectly) called from a web-service hosted by IIS (configured for x86 build).  I finally tracked it down to the Application Pool in IIS:  Originally I was using **"ASP.NET V4.0 Integrated"** (which resulted in that error), but when I changed it over to **"DefaultAppPool"**, the problem went away.

(Phew!)

Comment: I am using DefaultAppPool and getting the error, tread lightly!

Answer (score 0):

So, my issue was that SQLite was trying to load at design-time in WPF.  Since I cared only about x86 environment, I set the CPU preference to that and copied SQLite.Interop.dll from the Nuget package to the root directory of the solution.  Restarted the solution and all problems disappeared.  So, if you're having design-time issues, put the library into the root directory of your solution.

Additionally, I was getting a similar issue during runtime, so I had to place a copy of SQLite.Interop.dll into my project and set it to copy if it's newer in the properties.  It appears that x86 and x64 folders provided are completely useless.  Further investigation is required, but overall... it's just easier to manually reference SQLite in your project than to use a Nuget package.

Additionally, the official FAQ states the following:

> (20) When the System.Data.SQLite project is compiled and run from
>   inside Visual Studio, why do I get a DllNotFoundException or a
>   BadImageFormatException (for "sqlite3.dll" or "SQLite.Interop.dll")
>   when trying to run or debug the application?
>
> When compiling and running a solution from within Visual Studio that
>   uses the System.Data.SQLite project (including the test project), it
>   is very important to select the correct build configuration and
>   platform. First, managed applications to be debugged inside Visual
>   Studio cannot use the mixed-mode assembly (i.e. because it is always
>   compiled to the platform-specific build output directory). This is
>   necessary to properly support building binaries for multiple platforms
>   using the same source project files. Therefore, only the
>   "DebugNativeOnly" or "ReleaseNativeOnly" build configurations should
>   be selected when running a managed application from inside Visual
>   Studio that relies upon the System.Data.SQLite assembly. These build
>   configurations contain a custom post-build step that copies the
>   required native assembly to the managed output directory (i.e. to
>   enable running the managed binaries in-place). However, this
>   post-build step will only be performed if the selected platform
>   matches that of the operating system (e.g. "Win32" for 32-bit Windows
>   and "x64" for 64-bit Windows). Therefore, it is good practice to
>   double-check the selected build platform against the operating system
>   prior to attempting to run a managed project in the solution.

https://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/faq.wiki#q20

Answer (score 0):

Mine didn't work for unit tests either, and for some reason Michael Bromley's answer involving DeploymentItem attribute didn't work. However, I got it working using test settings. In VS2013, add a new item to your solution and search for "settings" and select the "Test Settings" template file. Name it "SqliteUnitTests" or something and open it. Select "Deployment" off to the right, and add Directory/File. Add paths/directories to your SQLite.Interop.dll file. For me, I added two paths, one each for Project\bin\Debug\x64 and Console\bin\Debug\x86. You may also want to add your Sqlite file, depending on how you expect your unit test/solution to access the file.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on Kugel’s answer which worked for me (VS2015 Enterprise) leveraging SQLite from a dll the Nuget package can be removed from the main project after building and testing:

1.Install Nuget package to main project.

```
Install-Package System.Data.SQLite
```

2.Build Application and test that your Sqlite connection is working:

```
select * from sqlite_master
```

3.Uninstall Nuget package from the main build.

```
UnInstall-Package System.Data.SQLite
```

4.Manually remove the dll references for SQLite and EntityFramework:

```
System.Data.SQLite
System.Data.SQLite.EF6
System.Data.SQLite.Linq
```

5. Remove Xml references from the main project's “packages.config” xml file.

This worked for me and keeps my project clean.

Answer (score 0):

In the **Nuget package** of SQLLite Core there is a the file **System.Data.SQLite.Core.targets** . Just include this in all projects that use the this library and all libraries that used your library.

In yours .csproj or .vbproj files add:

Every time you compile in your bin will added x86 and x64 directory with the SQLite.Interop.dll file.

Answer (score 0):

I tried pretty much all of the solutions here without any luck. Finally solved it by putting a copy of the SQLite.Interop.dll corresponding to my selected platform directly under the root of my setup project.

I have no idea why it worked but it did.

Answer (score 0):

Over 30 answers, and yet I solved it in a different way.

I had 2 separate projects. A Windows Service, and a Windows Forms app. The App references the WS project, and both reference the SQLite Core nuget package.

When building the WS project, the x64 and x32 folders are there. But when building the App, the folders don't show up.

Checking the answers here, I couldn't make them work. But I figured out that the following snippet was present in the WS project, and was missing in the App project. I added it, and the folders now show up correctly.

```
<Import Project="..\packages\System.Data.SQLite.Core.1.0.112.0\build\net46\System.Data.SQLite.Core.targets" Condition="Exists('..\packages\System.Data.SQLite.Core.1.0.112.0\build\net46\System.Data.SQLite.Core.targets')" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a solution.

In my case, I am using Microsoft Visual Studio Installer Project.
The setup project does not see the x64 and x86 folders and contents from primary outputs.

Solution:

1. Add both the x64 and x86 folders to the Application Folder in Setup.
2. Add the contents of both folders.

This will allow the setup to copy the DLL files needed for SQLite to work.

Answer (score 0):

One solution that worked for me was to install `System.Data.SQLite` from the nuget package.

Import the .dlls of the project you want to import and install `System.Data.SQLite`.

This will install the ddl compatible and updated with your solution/project.