# SQLite 'SQLite.Interop.dll' Error

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, sqlite

I tried to use SQLite in a C# program ,but I am getting the following exception:

Unable to load DLL 'SQLite.Interop.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)

I am using version 1.0.90.0 , compiling it in VS2012 on OS Win8.1 64bit.

It appears in Debug and Release config.
In VS Debug it points me to SQLite3.cs to the Line

```
SQLiteErrorCode rc = UnsafeNativeMethods.sqlite3_config_none(
                        SQLiteConfigOpsEnum.SQLITE_CONFIG_NONE);
```

Is there any solution for it ?

Comment: Change your project configuration to x86 or x64 to match the dll. This might solve your problem.

Comment: I tried this already but it does not even create a 'SQLite.Interop.dll' in my Programs folder

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to load DLL 'SQLite.Interop.dll'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13028069/unable-to-load-dll-sqlite-interop-dll)