# Programmatically create sqlite db if it doesn't exist?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, sqlite

I am trying to create an sqlite db programmatically if it doesn't exist. I have written the following code but I am getting an exception at the last line.

```
if (!System.IO.File.Exists("C:\\Users\\abc\\Desktop\\1\\synccc.sqlite"))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Just entered to create Sync DB");
    SQLiteConnection.CreateFile("C:\\Users\\abc\\Desktop\\1\\synccc.sqlite");
    string sql = "create table highscores (name varchar(20), score int)";
    SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(sql, sqlite2);
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
sqlite2 = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=C:\\Users\\abc\\Desktop\\1\\synccc.sqlite");
```

I get the exception at the line `command.ExecuteNonQuery();` The exception is `Invalid operation exception was unhandled`. Is there any other way to add an sqlite file to your project? Can I do it manually? If not then how can I solve the above issue?

Comment: What is the value of `sqlite2` at that point?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

To execute any kind of data definition command on the database you need an open connection to pass the command. In your code you create the connection AFTER the execution of the query.

Of course, after that creation, you need to open the connection

```
if (!System.IO.File.Exists(@"C:\Users\abc\Desktop\1\synccc.sqlite"))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Just entered to create Sync DB");
    SQLiteConnection.CreateFile(@"C:\Users\abc\Desktop\1\synccc.sqlite");
    
    using(var sqlite2 = new SQLiteConnection(@"Data Source=C:\Users\abc\Desktop\1\synccc.sqlite"))
    {
        sqlite2.Open();
        string sql = "create table highscores (name varchar(20), score int)";
        SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(sql, sqlite2);
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

However, if you use the version 3 of the provider, you don't have to check for the existence of the file. Just opening the connection will create the file if it doesn't exists.

Comment: Now Iam getting this exception "Unable to load DLL 'SQLite.Interop.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)" at the line where I open the connection

Comment: Hope this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13028069/unable-to-load-dll-sqlite-interop-dll

Comment: Weird thing is sqlite connection creation was working a few minutes ago but now I get exceptions

Comment: What version of the Sqlite provider are you using. The message is strange because I have the 1.0.82 and in this version the Interop is bundled together to the main assembly. No separate file is required. Perhaps you need to upgrade or reinstall the assembly. I am sorry but I don't use very often this database system and it has always worked without issues

Comment: This works after I manually copied the dll file to the directory. You forgot to open the DB otherwise your answer was correct.Thanks

Comment: Yes the initial version of the answer was without the call to Open, but I had fixed it.

Comment: Minor gotcha with the version 3 of the provider is that it will indeed create the file if it doesn't exist, but only if the full directory path already exists ahead of the file.

Comment: @Steve Your last two sentences should be bold or moved to the top of the answer. :-)

Comment: **var** sqlite2

Comment: To clarify for those reading, SQLite3, which is the current supported version, does not need you to create the file first, just open a connection to whatever path you want. You can create a zero byte file if you like. Here's a guide: https://www.beekeeperstudio.io/blog/sqlite-create-database