# Embed .sqlite database in .exe c# application

Tags: c#, sqlite

I want to embed the SQLite database into my C# windows form app (.exe) so I can give a very non-tech savvy client just the .exe file and nothing else. The database is read-write and I need to access its path for the DataSource like so:

```
 SQLconnect = new SQLiteConnection("DataSource=" + path + ";Version=3;Compress=True;");
```

I also tried saving the database to a folder on Desktop but SQLiteConnection.CreateFile(path) seems to fail because if I put the .exe file outside the bin/debug folder, .exe does not open at all (but it creates the necessary folder on Desktop).

But as long as it is in the bin/debug, it creates the database file and creates the tables and .exe works perfectly. There are no errors raised at any point in the application.

Comment: `so I can give a very non-tech savvy client just the .exe file and nothing else.` At a minimum you will also have the SQLIte assemblies, so thats not going to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To include the SQLite dlls you will have to modify the property of the reference and mark it as `Embedded Resource`. You will probably have to use [ILMerge](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=17630) See [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/114997/Embedding-and-Using-Resources-from-Net-Assembly).

You cannot embed the database. So, you have the following two choices :

1. You can create [In-Memory/Temporary database](https://www.sqlite.org/inmemorydb.html).

   var connection = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=:memory:");
2. Create the database on the go. On your application startup, you can create and seed the database. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24178930/programmatically-create-sqlite-db-if-it-doesnt-exist).