# SQLite Database Creation not being Created

Tags: vb.net, sqlite

I was storing my SQLite DB name in App.config and using System.Configuration Reference to retrieve the DB name
I decided this was of no value so I removed the readConfig code
Now I can not create the DB and its two tables
**Would someone be kind enough to review the code below and explain what I am doing wrong?**

Setting in Module

```
Public gv_dbName As String = "Notes.db"
```

Declarations top level on frmStart

```
Public connStr As String = "Data Source={0};Version=3;"
Public conn As SqliteConnection
Dim cmd As SqliteCommand
```

Other Relevant Code

```
    Private Sub frmStart_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Icon = Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(Application.ExecutablePath)
    connStr = String.Format(connStr, gv_dbName)

    If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(gv_dbName) Then
        btnCreate.Visible = False
        btnToEnterData.Visible = True
        btnToViewParentTable.Visible = True
    ElseIf Not My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(gv_dbName) Then
        conn = New SqliteConnection($"Data Source = '{gv_dbName}';Version=3;")
        tbMessage.Text = "Created Database & Tables"
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub btnCreate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCreate.Click
    makeDB()
End Sub

Public Sub makeDB()

    If Not My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(gv_dbName) Then
        Try
            conn = New SqliteConnection($"Data Source = '{gv_dbName}';Version=3;")
            conn.Open()
            makeParentTable()
            makeChildTable()
            conn.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            tbMessage.Text = "Database NOT Created"
        End Try
    End If

End Sub
```

I even tried this top level of frmStart

```
'Friend gv_dbName As String = "Notes.db"
```

Here is what I based this code off of
[Link to Code](http://dhamen.com/index.php/2017/12/create-sqlite-database-programmatically-using-vb-net/)

Comment: Why are you not using conn = New SqliteConnection(connStr)? Does the "($"Data Source = '{gv_dbName}';Version=3;)" even work the way you expect it to, honestly first time seeing something like that.

Comment: @CruleD You are correct that line of code conn = New SqliteConnection($"Data Source = '{gv_dbName}';Version=3;") Does not fire I commented it out still no results

Comment: @G3nt_M3caj Where would I put that code BIG question If the DB is not created how would the path even be known? Sorry I am lost

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that Notes.db is in your application directory (where the exe is), that's how you open a connection on sqlite. Just remove the options you don't need.

```
dim strConString As String = "Data Source=Notes.db;Version=3;Pooling=True;Synchronous=Off;journal mode=Memory;foreign keys=true;;"

conn = New SQLiteConnection(strConString)
conn.Open()
```

if it fails on Open() you can try to add `New=True` in the connection string

```
conn = New SQLiteConnection(strConString & "New=True;")
```

Comment: I added your strConString code top level on frmStart and  conn = New SqliteConnection(connStr & "New=True;") under makeDB Still no results  This is driving me crazy I have used similar code in another project and it works fine

Comment: Does your Note.db exists? Do you catch an exception? if so on which instruction and what is the message?

Comment: NO the Notes.db is not being created the fail is at makeDB but the issue is VS for some reason decided to Import Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.Core  I am suing System Data SQLite Core  Will try to FIX code Thanks for the help

Comment: If your DB doesnt exists you can create it with `SQLiteConnection.CreateFile(path)`. See the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24178930/programmatically-create-sqlite-db-if-it-doesnt-exist)

Answer (score 1):

Using `Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.Core` or `System.Data.SQLite` ***(Db Version 3)*** it doesn’t matter to see if file exists or not.
Just give a ***Phisical/Absolute*** path, if not exist there is created a new file `named.db` otherwise the existed database comes back:

Example:

```
Friend dbPath As String = IO.Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "Notes.db")

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    TestMySqlite()
End Sub


Private Sub TestMySqlite()
    Try

        'You can use this but it is not important for version 3 as is auto created the new file by itself
        'If Not IO.File.Exists(dbPath) Then SQLiteConnection.CreateFile(dbPath)

        Using conn As SQLiteConnection = New SQLiteConnection("Data Source=" & dbPath & "; Version=3;")

            conn.Open()
            Console.WriteLine(conn.FileName)

            Using command As SQLiteCommand = New SQLiteCommand("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  Test (RowIndex INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT COLLATE NOCASE, name varchar(20))", conn)
                command.ExecuteNonQuery()
            End Using

            Using cmdInsert = New SQLiteCommand("INSERT INTO Test (name) values ('this is a test')", conn)
                cmdInsert.ExecuteNonQuery()
            End Using

        End Using

    Catch ex As Exception
        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString)
        Stop
    End Try

End Sub
```

In this example is created a file (if not exist) named Notes.db under the folder your app is running.
The next call SQLiteConnection just return Notes.db

Comment: See the Update to the Question Issue is solved and the code I posted works the problem is VS imported MS Data SQLite Core I still do not understand how VS manages imports in Netbeans Imports are auto generated and ask if you want to import