# App crashes when i try to add data to my database

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I tried creating a database that would store the answers of users but I keep getting this error System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

```
  public class MySQLDatabase
{
    private SQLiteConnection conn;

    public void MyDatabase()
    {
        conn = new SQLiteConnection("mydatabase.db3");
        conn.CreateTable<MyTable>();
    }

    public void InsertData(int gameid, string preorder,string rating,string standards,string overpriced,string agerating,string gameplay,string recommend,string impact)
    {
        MyTable myNewTable = new MyTable
        {
            GameId = gameid,
            PreOrder = preorder,
            Rating = rating,
            Standards = standards,
            OverPriced = overpriced,
            AgeRating = agerating,
            Gameplay = gameplay,
            Recommend = recommend,
            Impact = impact
        };
        conn.Insert(myNewTable);
    }

    public void CloseConnection()
    {
        conn.Close();
    }
}

}
```

This is where i initialize it

```
 private void Button_Pressed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MySQLDatabase db = new MySQLDatabase();
        string q1 = Question1.ToString();
        string q2 = Question2.ToString();
        string q3 = Question3.ToString();
        string q4 = Question4.ToString();
        string q5 = Question5.ToString();
        string q6 = Question6.ToString();
        string q7 = Question7.ToString();
        string q8 = Question8.ToString();

        db.InsertData(5, q1, q8, q4, q3, q5, q6, q7, q2);
        db.CloseConnection();
    }
```

It seems that the table that i am trying to add to the database isn't getting populated or that's what i am getting from it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: @ConnorStoop so my error is that instead of populating my table I am just creating a new instance of it? But how do I fix it?

Comment: Where is conn initialized?  Why are you using MySQL instead of SQLite, which is the standard for on-device dbs?

Comment: @Jason I am using SQLite but i gave my class a bad name sorry about that. I also edited my question and added the whole MySQLDatabase class.

Comment: is `public void MyDatabase()` called before `InsertData` if not `conn` will be `null`

Comment: @sunboy not in your code sample of `Button_Pressed` , `public void MyDatabase()` is not the constructor

Comment: @ConnorStoop You were right I wasn't calling MyDatabase() but now i am getting a new error that says SQLite.SQLiteException: 'Could not open database file: mydatabase.db3

Comment: `SQLiteConnection` does not create a db file by default look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/24179042/2111137

Comment: @ConnorStoop How do I create one?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252157/discussion-between-connor-stoop-and-sunboy).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You open de db connection in `public void MyDatabase()` but this function is not called in `Button_Pressed`.
You might want to change the function to be a contructor like so:

```
public MySQLDatabase()
{
    conn = new SQLiteConnection("mydatabase.db3");
    conn.CreateTable<MyTable>();
}
```

That way it is always called before you can call `InsertData`.