# Unable to load DLL 'SQLite.Interop.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, sqlite, dll

I am doing one  WPF application in VS 2013 and trying publish it. As long as the application run within Visual Studio in release or debug mode, everything is fine. But when I publish the application and install from setup file and open application it give following error.

> Unable to load DLL 'SQLite.Interop.dll': The specified module could
>   not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E).

I have already tried solution of adding the missing file to project i.e. DLL 'SQLite.Interop.dll' and changing its properties like set Copy to Output Directory to Always Copy and "Build action = content" Change it in "Build Action = Embedded Resource" but its still not working giving same error.

Comment: What are you CPU-Settings? Any? X86? X64?

Comment: I tried with Any, X86 and X64 also but still not working

Comment: Which deployment package of system.data.sqlite did you use?

Comment: Lookup the hex error code using err.exe to get a clue as to what's gone wrong.

Comment: sqlite-netFx451-setup-x64-2013-1.0.96.0 for x64  and  x86  sqlite-netFx451-setup-bundle-x86-2013-1.0.96.0

Comment: Exact same error for me on VS2015 -- strangely enough IIS Express works just fine. Installed Sqlite using NuGet -- any ideas..?

Comment: Duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13028069/unable-to-load-dll-sqlite-interop-dll?page=1