# SQLite errors in VS 2010 Prof

Tags: c#, asp.net, sqlite

I have a ASP.NET we application and want to use SQLite

I finally managed get System.Data.SQLite 1.0.98.1 via Nuget in VS 2010 Professional but when I run the application I get the following error

`Unable to load DLL 'SQLite.Interop.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)`

I searched SO & internet and the solutions I read didn't work for me

How can I make SQLite work with ASP.NET?

Any ideas?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13028069/unable-to-load-dll-sqlite-interop-dll

Comment: I've seen that and nothing worked :-(

Comment: Have you tried this particular solution?  http://stackoverflow.com/a/24411049/3272586

Comment: I have Any CPU. I tried creating x64 and no use. I don't have an option to copy the dll to the bin folder via the "property" window. Any idea?