# How to avoid 'SQLite.Interop.dll' dependency in SQLite dll (.net 3.5)

Tags: c#, sqlite

Hi I want to use SQLite dll in my C# application which is .net Framework 3.5. I used nuget to add reference of SQLite in my project but no matter which nuget version I use for SQLite.

I always get:

> System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'SQLite.Interop.dll':
>   The specified module could not be found.

I understand why its coming becuase I dont have x86/x64 folders with correct dll but here is my Question... Is there any way to avoid this 'SQLite.Interop.dll' dependency in managed SQLite?  I was under impression that SQLite is just single dll deployment in most of cases. Another reason I just want single managed dll dependency .. because all my application dlls are going in GAC (Its Custom plugin for SQL Server so as per Microsoft requirement dll has to be in GAC)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to load DLL 'SQLite.Interop.dll'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13028069/unable-to-load-dll-sqlite-interop-dll)

Comment: I know error is same but my Issue is how to avoid 'SQLite.Interop.dll' .. I updated title.