# Unable to load DLL "SQLite.Interop.dll"

Tags: wpf, sqlite

I just finished a C# WPF application for a client that uses a SQLite database. The program launches fine, but whenever the program tries to do something with the database, I get this error in my Try Catch:

```
Unable to load DLL "SQLite.Interop.dll": The specified module could not be 
found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)
```

I read up on the other Stackoverflow questions and have not come up successful in any of the solutions. Note that I am building an installer with "Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 Installer Projects"

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
Setting Copy Local to True in all of my project References.
Using NuGet to obtain System.Data.SQLite, .Core and x64/x86.
Setting Any CPU to x64.
Prefer 32-bit false.
```

SQLite.Interop.dll and System.Data.SQLite.dll is inside of the the installed application's directory. This is not an issue on computers that have VS installed, only an issue on computers that don't have VS.

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13028069/unable-to-load-dll-sqlite-interop-dll

Comment: I stated in my original post that that thread was of no help.

Comment: Maybe the quickest way to find out is using some tool (e.g. ProcessMonitor) to monitor from which paths the application has tried to load the dll. Since from your description it is hard for others to recreate this issue on their own environment.

Comment: Seems the only work around was to install and uninstall VS 2017 with the .NET and SQL packages.