# Unable to load DLL 'SQLite.Interop.dll: The specified module could not be found.

Tags: c#, sqlite, visual-studio-2017

I installed SQL Lite in a Test Project using Visual Studio 2017.

I added the Nuget Package [System.Data.Sqlite](http://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Data.SQLite/). On a test I have the following:

```
using (SQLiteConnection connection = new SQLiteConnection(connSring)) {

  connection.Open();
  // remaining code

}
```

When I run it I get the error:

```
Unable to load DLL 'SQLite.Interop.dll: The specified module could not be found.
```

I changed the Build Plataform Target from "Any CPU" to "x86" and "x64" but nothing solved it.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to load DLL 'SQLite.Interop.dll'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13028069/unable-to-load-dll-sqlite-interop-dll)