# CustomAction failed-"Unable to load DLL 'SQLite.Interop.dll':The specified module could not be found.(ExceptionHRESULT: 0x8007007E)"

Tags: c#, sqlite, installation, wix, custom-action

I am trying to access the database from a custom action.However the connection is failing with a message "Unable to load DLL 'SQLite.Interop.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)".I want to know that where does a custom action looks for the SQLite.Interop.dll,while connecting to the database from within a custom action.The SQLite.Interop.dll is present in my install folder after installation as I have added it as a component in the product.wxs.

Comment: Haven't looked at this before that I recall, but there seems to be [lots of previous questions about it](https://www.google.com/search?q=SQLite.Interop.dll&oq=SQLite.Interop.dll). Here is one: [Visual Studio C# - SQLite.Interop.dll not found](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38594837/129130), and one more: [Unable to load DLL 'SQLite.Interop.dll'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13028069/129130)

Comment: Thanks @SteinÅsmul but I could not find a solution to the problem stated above.Hence, I changed my approach.Now,I am using the database from inside the application instead of the custom action.If you find a solution, please update me.

Comment: @SteinÅsmul, I have built basic installers for the application using wix toolset and in case of upgrade I change the version from 1.0.0.0 to 2.0.0.0.However, if I do the same thing with the current application, the earlier installed version disappears and the second version is not installed. I use the word disappear because I have scheduled custom action on uninstall of first application,the custom action does not get executed when I try installing the new version,. But I have nothing in control Panel as installed and all my folders related to the app are deleted

Comment: I commented my custom actions and it worked fine.But how to make it work with custom actions?

Comment: I figured out the reason, the update was not working with the custom action because the custom action in the installed application was getting executed when I was trying to install the update and for some strange reason instead for the update, my earlier application was disappearing and the new one was not getting installed.Now when I have scheduled the custom action to run only during install the application is getting updated.

Answer (score 1):

To give you a hint `Sqlite.Interop.dll` are under `x86` and `x64` folders and somehow Wix does not pick up subfolders under the CustomAction's bin folder. You need to somehow have these two folders install under C:\Windows\Installer\xxxxx`folder where you custom action`dll`files are copied during install. The problem I am having is that I cannot find the variable for that temp folder under`C:\Windows\installer`(that is different than`C:\User\Temp...`).

Reference:
[Program Unable to Load DLL 'SQLite.Interop.dll' after WiX Installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46340238/program-unable-to-load-dll-sqlite-interop-dll-after-wix-installation)