# Unable to load DLL 'SQLite.Interop.dll', but on another project it works fine

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, sqlite

I have created a Winforms application and am using SQLite 3 with Visual Studio 2017.  SQLite appears to be installed correctly (in fact, identically to another WinForms app in another solution, where it works fine). I am getting this:

"Unable to load DLL 'SQLite.Interop.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)"

The SQLite.Interop.dll is present in both the x86 and x64 subfolders of the bin/Debug/ folder.

The code is:

```
sqlConnection = new SQLiteConnection(ConnString);
sqlConnection.Open();
```

The exception is thrown when the connection is instantiated. The connection string is: `"Data Source=C:\\ImageDataDB.db;Version=3;New=False;Compress=True;"`

Comment: Maybe a DepandancyWalker trace to see if all the dependant DLLs exist.  The other thing that may yield clues is ProcessMonitor, run that quickly while you reproduce the problem and look for "File Not Found" or "Access Denied", good luck

Comment: does this project has the same target as the other project where it works ? 32/64 bit, same dotnet framework, etc...

Comment: Yes, @GuidoG, it does. I have now answered my own question after searching for the issue on Bing.

Comment: No kidding @MarkBenningfield! Check my answer! Sure, go ahead, why not?

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering my own question because I found the answer in another StackOverflow question.  Oddly enough, the question I found the answer in did not show up in a search on StackOverflow, but showed up as the first displayed SO result in a Bing search on "Unable to load DLL 'SQLite.Interop.dll'".

See the question with the successful answer [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13028069/unable-to-load-dll-sqlite-interop-dll).

Just to cut to the chase, the problem went away when I installed (via Nuget) the Sqlite libraries to the Winforms project, where previously they were only installed to the class library project that contained the actual Sqlite code. This installation was done by right-clicking the References of the Winforms project, selecting Manage Nuget Packages, and running the Sqlite installation from there.

I wondered if I would run into the problem again if I created a business layer project lacking the Nuget Sqlite package intermediate between the Winforms and data layer project (replacing the reference to the data layer project in the winforms project with the business layer project that itself referenced the data layer reference).  But the problem did not resurface.  So it's all good!