# Unable to load DLL 'SQLite.Interop.dll

Tags: sqlite, wcf, iis

I have a WCF service, which will visit SQLite database. Using Visual Studio WCF test Client, the service could start correctly, I can call the service function without any error. But when I move service to IIS, following exception was thrown when connect to database:

```
Unable to load DLL 'SQLite.Interop.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)
```

My service platform target is "Any CPU", the dll "System.Data.SQLite.dll" is x86, I download it by Nuget. How should I set IIS configure or my service to make it work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem by reference : https://stackoverflow.com/a/28092497/7352168+
Copy x86 and x64 SQLite.Interop.dll to IIS directory.