# Unable to load DLL 'SQLite.Inter The specified module could not be found

Tags: c#

Error #1: Unable to load DLL 'SQLite.Interop.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E).

What is causing this problem? And how to fix this issue please let me know the details.

We are trying to use the SQLite database in C# Application, to develop a C# application I am using Visual Studio 2015, System.Data.SQLite Version 1.0.108.
After building the project I am facing the following issue:

[image]

Comment: Is there the 'SQLite.Interop.dll' in the folder with your application? (e.g. the debug folder, or the folder where the release application is placed)

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem as well, and this fixed it for me:

Try to install the NuGet package to your project where you use SQLite classes and also install Sqlite.Core to your main project even if it does not have  any SQLite classes.
Based on this: [SQLlite error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13028069/unable-to-load-dll-sqlite-interop-dll)

Go to *Tools* -> *NuGet Package Manager* -> *Manage NuGet Packages for Solution* -> *Online* -> *All*. Then search there for SQLite and add System.Data.SQLite Core to your Startup project.

Comment: Thanks for the Response, And we tried your instructions but its still not working, we are facing the same issue.

Comment: Error #1: Unable to load DLL 'SQLite.Interop.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)

Question: What is causing this problem? And how to fix this issue please let me know the details.
 We are trying to use SQLite database in C# Application, to develop a C# application I am using Visual Studio 2015, System.Data.SQLite Version 1.0.108.
 After building the project I am facing the following issue.

Anyone let me know the Answer?