# How do I call SQLitePCL.Batteries.Init().?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sqlite

I am attempting to create an SQLite database for my application and have come across this error.

> System.Exception: 'You need to call SQLitePCL.raw.SetProvider().  If
>   you are using a bundle package, this is done by calling
>   SQLitePCL.Batteries.Init().'

I created a simple console app the run the exact same code for creation, with no issues. The code looks like this!

```
using (var dataContext = new SampleDBContext())
{
    dataContext.Accounts.Add(new Account() { AccountName = name, AccountBalance = balance });
}


public class SampleDBContext : DbContext
{
    private static bool _created = false;
    public SampleDBContext()
    {
        if (!_created)
        {
            _created = true;
            Database.EnsureDeleted();
            Database.EnsureCreated();
        }
    }
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionbuilder)
    {
        optionbuilder.UseSqlite(@"Data Source="Source folder"\Database.db");
    }

    public DbSet<Account> Accounts { get; set; }
}
```

Can anyone shed any light on the issue? I installed the same Nuget Packages on both projects, the only difference between the two is the Data Source and the POCO classes I used for the database.

Thanks.

**Edit**
My program currently consists of a `Console application` that references a `.Net Framework Class Library`. The `Console application` simple has a constructor that looks like this:

```
public Program()
{   
    using (var db = new FinancialContext())
    {
        db.Accounts.Add(new Account() { AccountName = "RBS", AccountBalance=20 });
    }
}
```

The Class Library has a FinancialContext as Follows:

```
public class FinancialContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Account> Accounts { get; set; }

    public FinancialContext()
    {
      # Database.EnsureDeleted();
        Database.EnsureCreated();
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionbuilder)
    {
        optionbuilder.UseSqlite(@"Data Source="Some Source Folder"\Database.db");
    }
}
```

The Above error is shown at the # symbol point, is there a problem with the way I am coding? I would really like to know what the issue is so I can fix it properly rather than apply a 'fix'. Also I tried the suggestion in the comments, but putting the code line `SQLitePCL.raw.SetProvider(new SQLitePCL.SQLite3Provider_e_sqlite3());` in the `Console Application` gave the error `SQLitePCL` is not in the current context, which leaves me thinking I am missing a reference?

Comment: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/88434/if-you-are-using-a-bundle-package-this-is-done-by-calling-sqlitepcl-batteries-init

Comment: Thank you Stuart, I saw this when searching for an answer, however this doesn't really say how you do this. I am creating a WPF application, would I enter this code in the OnStartup method? It's not really clear what this is doing really, just that someone placed a line of code somewhere in their application. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have edited the question with further comments, might possible add more detail to the question.

Answer (score 180, accepted):

This happened to me when I tried to avoid any additional dependencies and went for the `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite.Core` package.

You should install and use the `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite` package instead, which has a dependency upon the `SQLitePCLRaw` package.

Comment: This also works if you need to switch from `Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.Core` to `Microsoft.Data.Sqlite`.

Comment: Also rebuild solution before rerunning `dotnet ef database update`

Comment: Thank you! This was exactly what happened after using VS2019's quick refactoring/intellisense to automatically add missing package

Comment: Strangely, I use Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite.Core too, but still have this error

Answer (score 42):

Install `Nuget Package` `Microsoft.Data.Sqlite` (not `Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.Core`). (my version is 2.2.2)

and use **SQLitePCL.raw.SetProvider(new SQLitePCL.SQLite3Provider_e_sqlite3());**

```
 connection = new SqliteConnection("Data Source = Sample.db");

 SQLitePCL.raw.SetProvider(new SQLitePCL.SQLite3Provider_e_sqlite3());

 connection.Open();
```

but I advise use `nuget package` `System.Data.SQLite` instead `Microsoft.Data.Sqlite`

Comment: "I advise use nuget package System.Data.SQLite instead Microsoft.Data.Sqlite"

Why? I just had to switch from that to this because of this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13028069/unable-to-load-dll-sqlite-interop-dll and none of the solutions there worked well for me.

"SQLitePCL.raw.SetProvider" This was not needed for me (perhaps something changed since this solution was posted.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51933421/system-data-sqlite-vs-microsoft-data-sqlite

I read somewhere that the Linq2db team is recommended to use System.Data.SQLite, but I can't provide a link. In any case, the choice is yours.

Comment: Seems to be a simple choice!  System.Data.SQLite works as you'd expect it to.  Any questions?

Answer (score 13):

Switching from `Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.Core` to `Microsoft.Data.Sqlite` as Patrick said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50746465/how-do-i-call-sqlitepcl-batteries-init#comment118334555_51570139) did the trick for me

Answer (score 10):

I had this very exact error. It turned out that I had package `Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.Core` (2.2.4) installed, but not `SQLitePCLRaw.bundle_winsqlite3`.

Installing package `SQLitePCLRaw.bundle_winsqlite3` (1.1.13) solved the issue.

Answer (score 5):

I got this issue when working with `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite` version 3.1.10. The above solutions did not work for me. Then I have modified the My DbContext as follows (added `SQLitePCL.Batteries.Init();` to `OnConfiguring` method) and the issue is gone!!!

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlite("Data Source=mydb.db");
        SQLitePCL.Batteries.Init();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For some reason the `Nuget Package` hadn't installed the required references, reinstalled the package and it has corrected the issue!

Missing the `SQLitePCL.raw*` references.

Comment: You mean your issue was resolved by re-installing the package - and not by the other suggested resolutions, correct? I am asking because I have a similar issue where it's complaining: `Could not load file or assembly 'SQLitePCLRaw.core`. Like yourself, I'm also using `EF` (and not `EF Core`.

Comment: Yes that's correct nam - I just had to do a proper reinstall of the package and it worked - this was over two years ago but I'm guessing the same issue would apply :)

Comment: This answer led my focus on the build environment. For some reason, two of three SQLite related dlls were missing in my output directory.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when I try to use, Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite" Version="2.2.6". What I did was downgrade the version into 2.2.2 which I was previously used. Then issue not occur.

Answer (score -1):

On Xamarin.iOs I had the same problem.

Solution: Call `SQLitePCL.Batteries_V2.Init()` In the `FinishedLaunching` method of your `AppDelegate` class.

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/data/sqlite/xamarin