Is System.Data.SQLite faster than Microsoft.Data.SQLite?
According to https://stackoverflow.com/a/52235824/45843

I have tried System.Data.SQLite and Microsoft.Data.SQLite in a project, and I make a real world performace test, System.Data.SQLite is about 3x faster than Microsoft.Data.Sqlite when bulk insert.

and a comment adds

I found that just by swapping out Microsoft.Data.SQLite for System.Data.SQLite my regular select sum query was also about 3x faster

That was in 2019-20.
Are there any more systematic benchmarks comparing the performance of the two libraries in general? Is the picture still the same as it was a few years ago? Is there any explanation for the performance difference?

Okay, I tried a couple of simple benchmark tests on in-memory databases.
https://github.com/russellw/TestSystemDataSQLite
https://github.com/russellw/TestMicrosoftDataSQLite
Tentative conclusions:
Insert, both are equally fast.
Read, System.Data.SQLite is somewhat faster, very roughly 400 ms to 600 ms.
If anyone has more comprehensive benchmarks, happy to accept an answer with such.

I found that IDataReader.GetSchemaTable() is super slow in Microsoft.Data.SQLite. I have a table with 1 million rows and calling that method now take a few seconds to complete where with System.Data.SQLite it took milliseconds.
