# Cannot resolve type Mono.Runtime and Cannot resolve type System.CoreLib requested by System.Data.SQLite

Tags: c#, entity-framework

When I set provider for SQLite:

```
public class Configuration : DbConfiguration, IDbConnectionFactory
{
    public SqlTypeEnum sqlTypeEnum = SqlTypeEnum.Sql;

    public Configuration()
    {
        SetDefaultConnectionFactory(this);
    }

    public Configuration(SqlTypeEnum sqlTypeEnum)
    {
        this.sqlTypeEnum = sqlTypeEnum;
        SetProviderFactory("System.Data.SQLite", SQLiteFactory.Instance);
        SetProviderFactory("System.Data.SQLite.EF6", SQLiteProviderFactory.Instance);

        var providerServices = (DbProviderServices)SQLiteProviderFactory.Instance.GetService(typeof(DbProviderServices));

        SetProviderServices("System.Data.SQLite", providerServices);
        SetProviderServices("System.Data.SQLite.EF6", providerServices);
        SetDefaultConnectionFactory(this);
    }

    public DbConnection CreateConnection(string connectionString)
    {
        if(sqlTypeEnum == SqlTypeEnum.Sql)
            return new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        else
            return new SQLiteConnection(connectionString);
    }
}
```

This information appears on the console:

> Cannot resolve type Mono.Runtime requested by System.Data.SQLite, Version=1.0.113.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=db937bc2d44ff139

> Cannot resolve type System.CoreLib requested by System.Data.SQLite, Version=1.0.113.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=db937bc2d44ff139

after `SetProviderFactory("System.Data.SQLite", SQLiteFactory.Instance);`

Still, everything seems to be working fine, but I would want to repair that.

- .NET v4.5.2
- Entity Framework v6.4.4

Edit:

At last in my application I load the libraries of other projects, but I did a test directly for the project with the provider and it crashed an error indicating this problem: [Unable to load DLL 'SQLite.Interop.dll'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13028069/unable-to-load-dll-sqlite-interop-dll)

However, none of these solutions can solve the problem. It seems to me that the reason may be that libraries are loaded (Assembly) and I do not have any projects attached.

Comment: `Cannot resolve type Mono.Runtime requested by System.Data.SQLite, Version=1.0.113.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=db937bc2d44ff139` You sure you using the right version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not do that the information did not appear. This is a bug of the library that misinterprets targetframework. I have set:

```
<TargetFrameworks>netcoreapp2.2;netcoreapp3.0;net461</TargetFrameworks>
```

But run app on net461. Mono.Runtime and System.CoreLib do not apply to my framework.